# How to get Proftpd to completely hide a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, files, proftpd

Within my ftp tree there is a directory that I don't want to be accessible via anonymous.

I am able to hide the directory in question and all the files within the directory.

What I have not been able to do is prevent somebody from navigating to the directory.

So if somebody navigates to ftp.site.com they wont see an 'incoming' directory. However, if they navigate to ftp.site.com/incoming the page loads.

The files are hidden but this kind of nullifies the point of hiding the 'incoming' directory in the first place.

Any ideas would be much appreciated and if I've left anything out please me know.

Here are my configurations:

```
drwxr-xr-x  29 john     ftpgroup 4096 2012-04-17 22:22 incoming

<Anonymous /home/ftp/ftp.site.com>
    User  ftp
    Group ftp
    UserAlias    anonymous ftp

    <Directory incoming/>
        HideGroup ftpgroup

        <Limit READ DIRS>
            IgnoreHidden on
        </Limit>
    </Directory>
</Anonymous>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this worked for me.

I needed to add CWD to the 'Limit'

```
<Directory incoming/>
    HideGroup ftpgroup

    <Limit READ DIRS CWD>
        IgnoreHidden on
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

`chmod o-r ~ftp/incoming`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @alexus but anonymous can still navigate to the directory.

Comment: anonymous user won't see a directory listing so user wouldn't even know where to go unless user knows exactly the directory and then he can travel there.